# How to Print 2 dictionaries in 3 columns

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey guys so I have set up 2 dictionaries which have the same keys but different values for both. I am trying to get the code to print out like this

```
Digit     Count     % 
1         
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

The count is the countList and the % is the numFreq Values with their numbers also going down in the Count and % respectively.

Okay so the Data File looks like this (only doing some numbers because the file is pretty big

```
Census Data
Alabama Winfield    4534
Alabama Woodland    208
Alabama Woodstock   1081
Alabama Woodville   743
Alabama Yellow Bluff    175
Alabama York    2477
Alaska  Adak    361
```

the count is the number of occurences of the first digit of the number. I basically turned each line into a list and appended the last value of the list (the number) to a new list. So then I did a Count for how many times 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 , 7, 8 ,9 appear. That's what countList represents. So I stored that in a dictionary with the keys being the digits and the counts being the values. The % is the relative frequency of the count. So I set up a new list and calculated the relative frequency which is basically the count + the sum of all the counts and rounded it off to one digit. The % column has the relative count of each digit. I put that into a dictionary also where the keys are the digits 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. So now I just need to print these numbers into the 3 columns,

Here is my code so far

```
def main():
  num_freq = {}
  pop_num = []
  inFile = open ("Census__2008.txt", "r")
  count = 0
  for line in inFile:
    if (count == 0):
      count += 1
      continue
    else:
      count += 1
      line = line.strip()
      word_list = line.split()
      pop_num.append (word_list[-1])
  counts = {}
  for x in pop_num:
    k = str(x)[0]
    counts.setdefault(k, 0)
    counts[k] += 1
  countList = [counts[str(i)] for i in range(1,10)]
  sumList = sum(countList)

  dictCount = {}
  dictCount[1] = countList[0]
  dictCount[2] = countList[1]
  dictCount[3] = countList[2]
  dictCount[4] = countList[3]
  dictCount[5] = countList[4]
  dictCount[6] = countList[5]
  dictCount[7] = countList[6]
  dictCount[8] = countList[7]
  dictCount[9] = countList[8]
  num_Freq = []
  for elm in countList:
    rel_Freq = 0
    rel_Freq = rel_Freq + ((elm / sumList) * 100.0)
    rel_Freq = round(rel_Freq, 1)
    num_Freq.append(rel_Freq)
  freqCount = {}
  freqCount[1] = num_Freq[0]
  freqCount[2] = num_Freq[1]
  freqCount[3] = num_Freq[2]
  freqCount[4] = num_Freq[3]
  freqCount[5] = num_Freq[4]
  freqCount[6] = num_Freq[5]
  freqCount[7] = num_Freq[6]
  freqCount[8] = num_Freq[7]
  freqCount[9] = num_Freq[8]

  print ("Digit" "  ", "Count", "   ", "%")
  print (

main()
```

Comment: Could you clarify what digit, count and % are supposed to be again? Also, could you show how census__2008.txt looks like?

Comment: Done I added the census file and what I need in each column

Answer (score 1):

Using your code, you just need to do:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    print (i, dictCount[i], freqCount[i])
```

But you can simplify it a lot:

```
import collections

data = []

with open("Census__2008.txt") as fh:
    fh.readline()    # skip first line
    for line in fh:
        value = line.split()[-1]
        data.append(value)

c = collections.Counter([x[0] for x in data])
total = sum(c.values())
print("Digit", "Count", "%")
for k, v in sorted(c.iteritems()):
    freq = v / total * 100
    round_freq = round(freq, 1)
    print(k, v, round_freq)
```

Comment: Yeah I knew there was a way to simplify this code a lot and I'll experiment with it. Initially I just wanted to get it functional. Thanks a lot for the print statement that makes a lot of sense.